# php - find if an array contains an element

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array with just a list of ids, like so:

```
$my_array = array(
 12, 17, 99, 23
);
```

Now I know I could probably do something like:

```
function in_array($haystack = array(), $needle = NULL)
{
 foreach($haystack as $id)
 {
  if ($id == $needle)
  {return TRUE;}
  else
  {return FALSE;}
 }
}
```

but it seems like there's probably already a function built. What could I use?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No need to create one, it is already there co-incidentally with the same name you are using: [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) too.

**Example:**

```
if (in_array('foo', $array)){
  // foo is in the array
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's called [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) xD

Answer (score 2):

This might be a trick question. Anyway but how about [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)?