# Basic - If statement for a set of values

Tags: php

I have:

```
if($tha==1||$tha==2||$tha==3...){
echo 'correct';
}
```

$tha is a value from 1 to 10000, randomly chosen.

If it is the same as one of the number to check against, then echo.

I have the numbers to check against stored in a array if needed called $thaArray.  The count() on this array is 500.

Is there a way to make the if statement without typing all the elements I need to check against individually like above?

Comment: every time you are dealing with an array, a word **"loop"** should be blazing in your mind.

Comment: Please enclose $thaArray (some example)

Comment: Can you put the numbers to check against in another array? If you can, just use if (count(array_diff(array1, array2)) > 0 )

Comment: @Anzeo they don't like such links here :) 
It is more like a nursery actually here rather than programmers collaboration site

Comment: @Anzeo Would you mind if I use your link in my answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - find if an array contains an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416614/php-find-if-an-array-contains-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the numbers to check in an array and use `in_array`:

```
$primes = array(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13);
if (in_array($tha, $primes)) {
  echo 'correct';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will tell you whether a certain value can be found in an array.

```
$thaArray = array(1, 2, 3);
if (in_array($tha, $thaArray)) {
    ...
}
```

---

**[RTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) Note:**

Please try to familiarize yourself with the PHP manual. If you are working with an array, and you need a certain function, you have a great chance of finding it in the [Array Functions page](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

**Other handy tools:**

- StackOverflow - with one search you could find hundreds of similar questions with the same answer(s)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/in_array):

```
if(in_array($tha, $thaArray)) echo 'correct';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = range(1,500);
if (in_array($tha, $numbers))
{
   echo 'correct';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use the [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array) function. Your problem would be solved by:

```
<?php
if(in_array($tha, $thaArray)) {
    echo 'correct';
}
?>
```

That would do the desired..