# PHP - Compare a string to all in array and only echo once (unique)

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I'm trying to make a list of directories from a file. But I only want the list to contain unique entries i.e. - only echo once no duplicates.

Example: 
From this log file:

```
inactive : [2007-04-01 08:42:21] "home/club/member" 210.00 "r-200"
inactive : [2008-08-01 05:02:20] "home/club/staff" 25.00 "r-200"
active : [2010-08-11 10:12:20] "home/club/member" 210.00 "r-500"
inactive : [2010-01-02 11:12:33] "home/premier/member" 250.00 "r-200"
active : [2013-03-04 10:02:30] "home/premier/member" 250.00 "r-800"
active : [2011-09-14 15:02:55] "home/premier/member" 250.00 "r-100"
```

I want to echo the list of directories but no duplicates:

home/club/staff

home/club/member

home/premier/member

I used a foreach loop to iterate through the array but I don't know how to compare each value to each item in the array and then only output identical items once.

```
foreach($listofDir as $value) 
{
    echo "<p>" . $value .  "</p>";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - find if an array contains an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416614/php-find-if-an-array-contains-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just get your file into an array and then grab the paths out of each line.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $directorys = array_unique(array_map(function($v){
        preg_match("/.*? : \[.*?\] \"(.*?)\"/", $v, $m);
        return $m[1];
    }, $lines));

    print_r($directorys);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => home/club/member
    [1] => home/club/staff
    [3] => home/premier/member
)
```

Comment: Thanks, which part of that script ensures I'm not outputting an identical value?

Comment: @MauriceGreenland `array_unique()` So that you only have unique values